# Undefined reference to vtable - C++ linking error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, virtual, linker-errors

I'm pretty sure I defined every function in WaterHeater and its derived classes so anybody can tell me why I'm getting this linking error? Thanks a bunch in advance, it's been a while that I'm working on the issue without finding any solution.

Here's the error I'm getting when compiling my console project:

```
heater.cpp:(.text$_ZN11WaterHeaterC2ERKS_[_ZN11WaterHeaterC2ERKS_]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for WaterHeater'
[Error] Id returned exit 1 status
recipe for target 'LabProject4.exe' failed
```

Here's my code:

#### heater.h

```
class WaterHeater{

    public:

        void print() const;
        virtual WaterHeater* clone() const;
        virtual float installedPrice( const bool _hookUp, const bool _newVent) const = 0;
        float getPrice() const{ return d_price; };
};

class Tankless: public WaterHeater{

    public:

        Tankless( ...){} const;
};

class StorageTank: public WaterHeater{

    public:

        StorageTank( ...){} const;
};


float Tankless::installedPrice( const bool _hookUp, const bool _newVent ) const{...}

WaterHeater* Tankless::clone() const{...}

float StorageTank::installedPrice( const bool _hookUp, const bool _newVent ) const{...}

WaterHeater* StorageTank::clone() const{...}

void WaterHeater::print() const{...}
```

Comment: Please narrow it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your snippets are the actual ones used to compile your program, the issue is that the `WaterHeater::clone` method doesn't have an implementation.
It is a virtual method, hence the error outputted.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't define bodies for WaterHeater's two virtuals. I know they get overridden by derived classes, but then you should make them pure (=0;) or provide some dummy body.

Comment: Aha: I see that installedPrice is pure, so the problem is with clone, as stated by the other answer.